# My teacher used this function as an example in class, but I wasn't there for it. Can someone help me, just explain what it does?

Tags: c++

```
void reverse(char *s, int n) {
    char *first = &s[0];
    char *last = &s[n-1];
    int k = 0;

    while(first < last){
        char temp = *first;
        *first++ = *last;
        *last-- = temp;  
        k++;
    }
}
```

It's supposed to demonstrate how it uses pointers, addressing, dereferencing, incrementing and, decrementing to access values and addresses.

I can tell what a few lines do, but as I unfortunately arrived after the example, I missed it, which sucks because the lecture was based on this example, so I'm kinda lost now. Thanks in advance! I've been pulling my hair out over this for all of today.

Comment: I'm sure if you approach your teacher with this question, your teacher should be happy to help.

Comment: Then go back and ask your instructor to explain it to you.

Comment: if it doesn't reverse I'll be a little upset at the naming convention.

Comment: Step through it line by line. Draw a chart with boxes to represent memory locations and arrows to represent pointers pointing to those locations and keep track of all the values as you step through the code. Or run it in a debugger and do the same thing.

Comment: Going to lectures is a good idea !! Also I'd argue that this is not c++ this is c.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would, but he's out today, and it'd be helpful to understand this by lecture time tomorrow so that I can understand tomorrows lecture- which is a part 2 to yesterdays.

Comment: @PaulRooney I only missed the first 10 minutes or so, when he was explaining this, they're doing work on the parking lots and had to close one down. I had to park on the other side of campus, very annoying haha.

Comment: @Determine I was only teasing. I certainly missed my share back in the day. But on a more serious note, did you try to run it, do you know how to run it? The name is pretty self explanatory if you understand what `char*` signifies.

Comment: @GregKikola Oh, thank you! I didn't think of doing it that way, (either way).

Comment: My snide comment is being upvoted more than @GregKikola 's excellent advice. There is something seriously wrong with that. Determine, if you take no other advice here, do what Greg suggests. Asking the teacher's a fine and good, but figuring stuff out is what gets you ahead.

Comment: @PaulRooney I hate missing class >.< makes me upset lol

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah I'm about to follow his advice. Your comment made me chuckle though, which is something I've needed today. So thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk through the code:

```
void reverse(char *s, int n) {
```

declares a function named `reverse`, returning no value and accepting a `char*` and an `int` as arguments. From the name, we should expect this function to reverse the contents of the string `s`, where `s` has length `n`.

```
    char *first = &s[0];
```

`first` now points to the first character in the string `s`.

```
    char *last = &s[n-1];
```

`last` now points to the last character in the string `s`.

```
    int k = 0;
    while(first < last){
```

initializes a counter `k` and starts a loop. As long as the address stored in `first` is less than the address stored in `last`, the `while` body will execute.

```
        char temp = *first;
        *first++ = *last;
        *last-- = temp;
```

Ignore the increments and decrements for now. This code is just swapping the characters `*first` and `*last`. `first` points initially to the first character in the string, `last` points to the last, so this will swap these values.

In addition to the swapping, the postfix increment operation `first++` will increment `first` so that it points to the next character in the string, and `last--` will decrement last so that it points to the previous character in the string. When `first` and `last` meet each other, the `while` condition will be false and the loop will stop.

The order of evaluation in the statement `*first++` can be a little tricky. It's equivalent to `*(first++)`. The post increment `++` has higher precedence, so `first` is incremented, but its previous location is returned as the result of the subexpression. Then that old location is dereferenced to get the corresponding character in the string. You can think of this as dereferencing `first` and *then* incrementing its address, although technically the `++` is evaluated first.

Finally,

```
        k++;
```

just increments the counter `k`. `k` is never used in this function so I'm not sure what it's purpose is here.

Then the loop starts over again, and so on until `first >= last`.

Comment: So, if I have this right, it's just reversing as it iterates through a string, so, for example if the string were "Hello world" it would be "olleH dlrow"? but it's doing it with pointers and addresses?

Comment: Well, "dlrow olleH" but yes.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! This explanation helps a lot. I'm gonna follow your advice still, though, and go through it myself so I can understand it. Thanks again!